# select xml node unable to pick out specific data

Tags: asp-classic

```
<B:CreditVehicle>
<B:Model>Accord Sedan</B:Model>
<B:ModelYear>2014</B:ModelYear>
<B:ModelDescription>CR2F3EEW</B:ModelDescription>
<B:Make>Honda</B:Make>
<B:SaleClass>Used</B:SaleClass>
<B:Condition>CLEAN</B:Condition>
<B:CertifiedPreownedInd>0</B:CertifiedPreownedInd>
<B:VehicleNote>4dr I4 CVT LX</B:VehicleNote>
<B:VIN>1HGCR2F37EA078469</B:VIN>
<B:DeliveryMileage uom="M">101550</B:DeliveryMileage>
<B:VehicleDemoInd>0</B:VehicleDemoInd>
<B:Pricing>
<B:VehiclePrice currency="USD">11100</B:VehiclePrice>
<B:VehiclePricingType>MSRP</B:VehiclePricingType>
</B:Pricing>
<B:Pricing>
<B:VehiclePrice currency="USD">12149</B:VehiclePrice>
<B:VehiclePricingType>Selling Price</B:VehiclePricingType>
</B:Pricing>
<B:Pricing>
<B:VehiclePrice currency="USD">8925</B:VehiclePrice>
<B:VehiclePricingType>Wholesale Price</B:VehiclePricingType>
</B:Pricing>
<B:CollateralType>1</B:CollateralType>
<B:AuctionInd>0</B:AuctionInd>
<B:VehicleUse>7</B:VehicleUse>
</B:CreditVehicle>
```

In the above XML file I am tryign to cherry pick the "Wholesale Price" value of "8925".  I was trying to do so by selecting a single node, but I have not been able to.

This is what I was trying to do:

```
Set Node = xmlDoc.documentElement.selectSingleNode("D:Body/B:ProcessCreditApplication/B:DataArea/B:CreditApplication/B:Detail/B:CreditVehicle/B:Pricing[@VehiclePricingType='Wholesale Price']/B:VehiclePrice")
```

I have been able to get values using the "selectsinglenode" option, but perhaps this structure of the XML makes it not possible to reach.

Anyone have an idea or experience to do it in a simple manner?

Comment: You have tagged this with asp-classic.  This looks more like asp.net